# Firebase dynamic link not being created - Ionic

Tags: facebook, firebase, ionic-framework

I have been following numerous Ionic tutorials on youtube to create a Facebook login feature using Firebase. One of the steps requires creating a dynamic link, I have tried to follow the steps but I seem to keep on getting the following error:

An error occurred when fetching Dynamic Links creation history firebase

The video I have been following (note link starts at 8mins where he creates the dynamic link):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=stxCOBr5d8o&t=480

Has anyone come across this problem and been able to resolve it? (I have also followed the steps from other videos but comes up with the same error)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So this was the response from Firebase support:

> I was able to replicate your issue on my end with the newly created
>   project. An internal bug has been filed, though I can't provide any
>   details or timelines on when the fix will be released.
>
> As a workaround, kindly try to do the following: Restart the browser
>   and login again. Make sure that you're not logged in to multiple
>   Firebase accounts. In order to display your Dynamic Link Domain, you
>   should create a sample dynamic links on your Firebase Console and
>   manually refresh your Firebase Console to propagate the link creation.
>   We appreciate bringing this issue to us and help us improve our
>   system.

I tried following the steps as advised by customer service without success. I guess I will have to wait until this is resolved or find an alternative solution.